# Allow two ports on multi-region ingress for GKE service

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, gke-networking

I have two ports on node.js, 4000 and 5050, open for normal api and web socket (require session affinity for web socket) respectively.

Below is my mcs.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: MultiClusterService
metadata:
  name: terraback-mcs
  namespace: terraback
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      selector:
        app: terraback
      ports:
        - name: web
          protocol: TCP
          port: 8080
          targetPort: 4000
```

mci.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: MultiClusterIngress
metadata:
  name: terraback-ingress
  namespace: terraback
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      backend:
        serviceName: terraback-mcs
        servicePort: 8080
```

deployment.yaml

```
# Copyright 2021 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: terraback-instance
  namespace: terraback
  labels:
    app: terraback
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: terraback
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: terraback
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: terraback-app
        # Replace $LOCATION with your Artifact Registry location (e.g., us-west1).
        # Replace $GCLOUD_PROJECT with your project ID.
        image: us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/terraback-v2/terraback-repo/terraback-instance:latest
        # This app listens on port 8080 for web traffic by default.
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
          - name: PORT
            value: "8080"
---
```

How should I make changes to allow additional port 5050?

I have tried the method from Zer0, with the modification of mci from [validation error for multiingress yaml file for GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927220/validation-error-for-multiingress-yaml-file-for-gke/72929175#72929175) and it works.

Comment: Where is your node.js app? And what is the flow of traffic you're trying to achieve? The provided manifests suggest that you have an application running at port 8080 in your deployment. And another service and ingress that forward traffic received on 8080 port (external) to port 4000 inside the cluster. These are two incompatible configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an additional port in your `terraback-mcs` service. This will serve the web socket connections. The following changes will be required:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: MultiClusterService
metadata:
  name: terraback-mcs
  namespace: terraback
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      selector:
        app: terraback
      ports:
        - name: web
          protocol: TCP
          port: 8080
          targetPort: 4000
        - name: web-socket
          protocol: TCP
          port: 8081
          targetPort: 5050
```

You will then need to add an additional backend to your `MultiClusterIngress`. This can be done as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: MultiClusterIngress
metadata:
  name: terraback-ingress
  namespace: terraback
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      backend:
        serviceName: terraback-mcs
        servicePort: 8080 # <==== This gets routed to service port 8080->4000
      rules:
      - host: web.socket.hostname #<==== adjust this as needed
          http:
            paths:        
              - backend:
                serviceName: terraback-mcs
                servicePort: 8081 # <=== This gets routed to servicePort 8081 => 5050
```

This `Ingress` will route incoming requests to the provided `host` if there is a match. Otherwise, the connection will be forwarded to the `default` host, which will be your API service.

I hope this gives you an idea of how to configure multiple ports with `MultiClusterService` and `MultiClusterIngress` objects. I'm unsure what is the point of the `terraback-instance` deployment. I don't believe this is your Node.JS application, since it neither exposes port `5050` nor port `4000`. It it is your application indeed, then you need to expose both ports, correctly as:

```
ports:
  - name: api-port
    containerPort: 4000
  - name: web-socket-port
    containerPort: 5050
```

### Summary

The traffic flow will be like this:

1. All incoming traffic on the hostname `web.socket.hostname` will be rerouted by the ingress to the service with port `8081`. This, will be routed by the service, to the container port `5050`.
2. All the incoming traffic *other than the hostname* above, will be rerouted by the Ingress to the Service on port `8080`. This, will be routed by the service, to the container port `4000`.

Understand that Ingress objects process the incoming traffic on the basis of a `host` and `path` matching. And forward to backend services on certain ports based on the result of this match. In the current configuration, the ingress rule is defining a default backend only, because of which all the traffic coming in, will be forwarded to the same backend service configured.

Once you make these changes, the ingress will separate traffic based on the `host` and forward the traffic to the appropriate service backend.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, say if my external ip is 35.35.35.35, (1) opening two ports 8080 and 8081 (2)have a new host like web.socket.hostname, how do I access nodejs path (e.g., /health) and web socket via 35.35.35.35? Currently I only open port 8080 (without integrating your suggestion yet), and why can I still access using 35.35.35.35/health for nodejs path on port 80?

Comment: Please see the update above for the summary. Currently, you're routing all of your traffic (as default backend in ingress) the service with port `8080`, which the service is rerouting to your application at port `4000`. The port number here doesn't matter, since the ingress, by design will only work with http requests (which is port 80). What matters in the ingress is the `hostname` and/or `the path`. Which,  because of the default rule is matchine all the incoming traffic. Please try the suggestion and let me know, it should work.

Comment: for web.socket.hostname, do I need to change the A record of my dns for say "socket.domain.com" to point to the external IP address?

Comment: Yes. If you are manually handling the DNS.

Comment: Thanks, I have this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927220/validation-error-for-multiingress-yaml-file-for-gke when run the multi-ingress yaml as suggested by you, but looks like the syntax is correct. Also do you know where we can get detailed specification for the yaml?

Comment: I've been trying to find it but it appears Google hasn't published the schema anywhere :/ I answered on your question, essentially, try setting ``--validate=false`` since this appears to be a bug.

Comment: Hi, I think the mci syntax has some issues, and it does not work, after changing to syntax I highlighted in my answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927220/validation-error-for-multiingress-yaml-file-for-gke, it works, thanks zer0.

Comment: Great! I'll update the answer as well :)